# Android Broken SMS sending code

Tags: android, sms

Ok, so i am making a Android app that is able to send sms msgs multiple times with intervals between the amount of messages is sent. This is partially working but it sometimes does not. For example when i input 20 msgs to send it sends 16 or maybe a little more. Also when i push the button it freezes until it finishes sending the SMS's.is there anyway that someone could tell me what is wrong with my code? i have tried a few fixs that are not working very well and thought i would come here for help after many failed trys at this. PS there is more code then this but this is where the issue resides i beleive. Thanks for reading
EDIT: FIXED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is "freezing" because the UI thread is sending all 20 SMS before it frees up to do other things.

I would look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This is Android's way to easily thread. Essentially what you would do it spawn a new thread in the background with AsyncTask. This frees up the UI thread so that it looks like everything is normal to the user (no freezing), while the AsyncTask is doing all of the work in the background with `doInBackground`. Then when the Task is done use `onPostExecute` to notify the UI that it is done and perhaps tell the user something. You'd put the call to `MyAsyncTask.execute(smsDataHere)` in the onClick.

That link to AsyncTask is fairly comprehensive for simple purposes and has example code.

I'm not sure *exactly* why it only send 16 or so messages, but I can see right off the bat that you are missing some curly braces and that they don't quite match up the way you want them to. I would look there first. Also, is there a reason for the second `for` loop? `size` is always 1, so it is just sending each message twice.

**EDIT:**
Here is some sample code. I'm not going to promise it works in your exact app, but it will show you how the AsyncTask works and give you a starting point. I also tried to fix any problems with the curly braces and did a little cleaning up. I still recommend looking over the documentation to make sure you understand how it works. I hope this helps you.

```
public void onClick(View v){                
    String phoneNo = putpn.getText().toString();
    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
    String txts = txtAmount.getText().toString();
    String inter = interval.getText().toString();

    if (msgCount > 21){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "That is too many txts, the max is 20", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        MySmsTask.execute(phoneNo, message, txts, inter);
    }
}

private class MySmsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... messageData) {
        int sentCount = 0;
        int size = 1;
        int delay = Integer.parseInt(messageData[3]);
        int msgCount = Integer.parseInt(messageData[2]);

        if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0){
            for (sentCount = 0; sentCount < msgCount; sentCount++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    sendSMS(messageData[0], messageData[1]);
                    Thread.sleep(delay * 1000);
                }
            }
        }
        return sentCount;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent " + sentCount + " messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Object.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Comment: OK i will try what you have suggested and implement Asynctask instead of the Thread. also im getting syntax errors in there but am confused because i see no errors besides the off brackets.

Comment: Also may i ask that you show a example of how i would go about making a doInBackground(method?)? and what exactly would i put into the MyAsynctask method? sorry im really new with java/android and this is my first app.

Comment: also the steps i think are.
1.do a onPreExecute for a progress bar
2.make the MyAsyncTas Class(dont know exactly what to put into here)
3.make a doInBackground to run the Async class in?
4.Then call in (I dont know what i would call in here, doInBackground)?
5.run onPostExecute

Comment: Also the second     for loop is for later use. i plan to eventually implement a contact selector that selects more then 1 contact. then i will replace the size with how many contacts are selected.

Comment: I would do it like this: pass in the phone number, message, etc. through `execute` then use them in `doInBackground` which contains all that you are currently doing in the big `else` block. Then just put the `MyTask.execute(String[] data)` after the else. Then in `onPostExecute` put some sort of message to the user if you'd like. I wouldn't bother to use the other methods (`onProgressUpdate` and `onPreExecute`). Try to thoroughly read and understand the AsyncTask and I think you'll see how its supposed to work. You can pretty much use the same framework they have for the class, and paste yours

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about the errors you are getting?

Comment: where exactly would i be putting this? how would i go about making this new class and such. do you mind putting up a example? I read through the documentation on the link but im still kinda confused on how i should go about this. my syntax for my code is also messed up like crazy. Im having huge difficulties with that also/. but once i get this class and such working i will hopefully work out the syntax way more easily in the program.

Comment: How would i go about sending all my variables into this new class? I am very new to this and am learning as i go sorry for all the beginner questions.

Comment: Also, as a reminder since this is your first post: on Stack Overflow, you accept someones answer by clicking the check mark so that they get credit for answering. Thanks!

Comment: OK that helped alot and i got it all setup but now when i try to execute the MySmsTask it tells me that"MySmsTask cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: All the code I provided needs to go outside the Activity's `onCreate()` but within the `smsSender` class....except the `onClick()` method which you have in the right place within the button's `onClickListener`.

Comment: Ok now i have this error: The method MySmsTask() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}